# How to add context menu to datatables 1.10?

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, datatables

I'm using `DataTables` (datatables.net) and I would like to add a context menu to my table.

I found [jQuery contextMenu](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html) and also description in the `DataTables` forum on how somebody implemented the context menu.
But it seems that at least the `DataTables` I'm currently using (1.10) has evolved quite much.
I have not information about the `Context Menu` plugin. (meaning what version was using in this forum post and what I have downloaded).

If I use it as described in the forum post and adapt it to 1.10 (to my humble knowledge) I'm comming to this

```js
var myTable = $("#myTable ").DataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        $("#myTable tbody tr").contextMenu(
        {
            menu: 'myMenu'},
            function( action, el, pos ) {
                var aData = myTable.GetData( el.context );
            }
        );
    }
} );
```

**But executing this code will give me this error:**

> Uncaught Error: No selector specified  in jquery.contextMenu.js:1273

Has anybody recently implementet context menu to `DataTable` 1.10?

Comment: I have just updated my answer to full support DataTables 1.10 with the new methods. Hope it helps! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have just see this question, and would like to answer it because I was looking for a solution for this.

Here you have a demo using [jquery.ui-contextmenu](https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu): [DEMO](http://live.datatables.net/caderego/1)

I use jquery.ui in addition, hope this won't be a problem for you.

It is integrated with functions `fnFilter()` and `fnFilterClear()`, so you can filter data using right-click.

Thanks!

**UPDATE: DataTables 1.10 API style!**

Removed `fnFilter()` and `fnFilterClear()` and use the new `search()` API method.

[DEMO](http://live.datatables.net/savuvija/1) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks quite nice.